# Removing a user from a specific user group

Tags: rest, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I need to make a call on the BOX API to remove a user from a group. I looked at the BOX API documentation - https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#delete-a-group-membership. The RESTful call is:

DELETE https://api.box.com/2.0/group_memberships/group_membership_id

However, it does not tell me how to **remove a user from a specific group**. Is this possible? If yes, what is the API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that by deleting membership, you're deleting the user form the group.

This is an example of how a group membership looks like:

```
[
        {
            "type": "group_membership",
            "id": "1560354",
            "user": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "13130406",
                "name": "Alison Wonderland",
                "login": "alice@gmail.com"
            },
            "group": {
                "type": "group",
                "id": "119720",
                "name": "family"
            },
            "role": "member"
        }
    ]
```

So, by calling https://api.box.com/2.0/group_memberships/1560354 you would remove user Alison Wonderland form the group family

Comment: I suspected that. But how about if the user is part of  multiple groups? You do not want to remove the user from ALL groups. There has to be a way to mention a specific group.

Comment: The id is just for that one group, for the next group membership you would have the new json object with different group id that looks just like this one. I think this will do what you want. And if you want to remove a user from all groups. You could use https://api.box.com/2.0/users/user_id/memberships to get all user memberships and then make a loop to delete all memberships for that user

Comment: I get it now, the user id is different from the group membership id.